# How should types like `Country = "United States" | "Canada" | ...` be represented in GraphQL?

Tags: typescript, enums, graphql, graphql-codegen

Using https://graphql-code-generator.com/, the type in GraphQL is just set to `String`, but in my client code with the dropdown input, the type is more specific because it is derived from the dropdown options themselves:

```
export const CODE_NAME_MAP = {
  AFG: 'Afghanistan',
  AGO: 'Angola',
  // ...
export type Country = typeof CODE_NAME_MAP[keyof typeof CODE_NAME_MAP]
```

In this case, the graphql data returned from the server has a less specific type than what the client does. Is there a better way to represent these types so they're the same? I got validation errors trying to use the country names in an enum.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to help since you haven't provided what the expected type is, but have you considered declaring an [Object Type](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/object-types/)? Then you can match the type to what you're expecting and assign it correctly within your schema.